# How to approximate table-defined function using non-linear least squares

Tags: approximation

I read [least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) and haven`t found a good example of using non-linear least squares.

**Problem:** I have an arbitrary values for x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, therefore, I have a table-defined function. I have to approximate this function using the non-linear least squares method and then extrapolate values for x = 0, 6.

**P. S.** I attempts to be a programmer, not a mathematician. I appologize and ask you to correct me if something I wrote is wrong.

Comment: You may receive more constructive answers if you post this question at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TonyHellmuth thank you so much ;)